# Scheduled radio stream recording software

Tags: scheduling, audio-recording, radio

I am looking for Windows or Linux software to record a radio stream on a schedule. For example, start recoring a radio stream every day at 8:00AM for 4 hours.

Currently I am using AIMP which offers recording feature but not scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues really:

1. How to record an audio stream, (radio station), from the command line or similar
2. How to schedule its execution

### Command Line Record

You can use *(on both platforms)* [Video LAN VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org) *(Free & Open Source)* from the command line or shell.  There are lots of command line options but amongst them are options to stream from a URL,

```
-I dummy
VLC should run with no GUI, typing error messages and asking for input in the command line window. This is better for scripting and for faster completion

--run-time=<float [-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 .. 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000]> 
                             Run time
      The stream will run this duration (in seconds).
```

There is a special target that should come after the URL for the radio station

```
vlc://quit
```

This will case VLC to end after the stream run duration.
There are a lot of options for how to control the audio save format, etc., [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Extract_audio/) page is quite helpful as is the [command line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/).

Once you have worked out *(and tested)* your command line you need to save it as a batch file `.bat` on Windows or a bash script on Linux (or other shell script):

### Schedule For A Given Time

This differs between Windows and Linux:

- **Linux** - simple use [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux)
- **Windows 10** - [Use Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)

In both cases you will need to ensure that the script is accessible when you are not logged on, has access to VLC, has write permissions in the destination directory and *in Linux* is executable.

***Note:*** Personally I would suggest ensuring that the destination device is not your Operating System device just in case you don't get around to listening to & deleting your recordings for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Look for StreamWriter, all you need is there. https://streamwriter.org/en/

Succes

Comment: Hi, these answrs need to be complete. The rwaders shouldn't have to click a link to get the answer. Please edit it and improve it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66862)